# Can't find any way to keep already mapped UV's from a geometry node

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

I've spent well over an hour trying to find substitutes for geometry nodes not exporting/saving UV data. I've tried using the 'make instances real' command recommended by other users with this issue with no success because of the use of curves in my geometry node setup, I've seen the 'attribute' route of fixing this but since I'm exporting this via an FBX to an off-topic program this won't help. Are there any alternatives I'm missing that can fix my situation?

My blender version: 3.0.1

Comment: I think we're all in that boat right now, just waiting for UV data to be included in GN. [I asked about it recently too](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254282/).

Comment: Yeah, I recently ran into the same issue. Read up on the developer thread about it, and they (appear) to be working on it, but no progress yet really: https://developer.blender.org/T85962